# Quadratic Trendline in Plotly.js?

Tags: plotly, regression, plotly.js, quadratic, trendline

I was recently making a Kinetics web program that required a linear and **quadratic trendline**. I decided to use **plotly.js** as I am familiar with it. Everything was going smooth until I realized that there wasn't an easy shortcut to plot the quadratic line in respect to the scatter plot points.

So naturally I went to google, youtube, and stack overflow to see if anyone else programmed something similar. To my surprise **my searches came up empty**. So I figured it out myself and posted it here for future programmers. **Here is my solution**.

Pass x and y array's and it will return a, b, and c of the quadratic formula (ax^2 + bx + c) along with the new array of y points.

This is how I called the function:  `var trendQR = trendlineQuadratic(xCol, yCol);`

And to use the **variables** it's as simple as `trendQR.a, trendQR.b, trendQR.c, trendQR.yPoint[i]`

And finally to **create the trend line in plotly.js** I used :

```
var fitQuadratic = {
    x: xCol,
    y: trendQR.yPoint,
    mode: 'lines',
    type: 'scatter',
    name: 'y = ' + trendQR.a.toPrecision(4) + 'x<sup>2</sup> + ' + trendQR.b.toPrecision(4) + 'x + ' + trendQR.c.toPrecision(4)
  };
```

**Quadradic Trendline Function:**
(ps - you can check the math with the included `console.log()`'s)

also the variable sum_xxxx for example basically means the sum of all x's to the 4th power (hence the 4 x's)

```
function trendlineQuadratic(x,y){
        var qr = {};
        var n = y.length;
        var sum_x = 0;
        var sum_y = 0;
        var sum_xy = 0;
        var sum_xxy = 0;
        var sum_xx = 0;
        var sum_xxx = 0;
        var sum_xxxx = 0;

        var yPoint = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {

            sum_x += parseFloat(x[i]);
            sum_y += parseFloat(y[i]);
            sum_xy += (x[i]*y[i]);
            sum_xxy += (x[i]*x[i]*y[i]);
            sum_xx += (x[i]*x[i]);
            sum_xxx += (x[i]*x[i]*x[i]);
            sum_xxxx += (x[i]*x[i]*x[i]*x[i]);

        }

        var sx_x = sum_xx - (sum_x * sum_x / n);
        var sxy_xy = sum_xy - (sum_x * sum_y / n);
        var sx_xx = sum_xxx - (sum_xx * sum_x / n);
        var sxx_y = sum_xxy - (sum_xx * sum_y / n);
        var sxx_xx = sum_xxxx - (sum_xx * sum_xx / n);

        qr['a'] = ((sxx_y * sx_x) - (sxy_xy * sx_xx)) / ((sx_x * sxx_xx) - (sx_xx * sx_xx));
        qr['b'] = ((sxy_xy * sxx_xx) - (sxx_y * sx_xx)) / ((sx_x * sxx_xx) - (sx_xx * sx_xx));
        qr['c'] = (sum_y / n) - (qr['b'] * sum_x / n) - (qr['a'] * sum_xx / n);

        // console.log('sum_x : ' + sum_x);
        // console.log('sum_y : ' + sum_y);
        // console.log('sum_xy : ' + sum_xy);
        // console.log('sum_xxy : ' + sum_xxy);
        // console.log('sum_xx : ' + sum_xx);
        // console.log('sum_xxx : ' + sum_xxx);
        // console.log('sum_xxxx : ' + sum_xxxx);
        // console.log('sx_x : ' + sx_x);
        // console.log('sxy_xy : ' + sxy_xy);
        // console.log('sx_xx : ' + sx_xx);
        // console.log('sxx_y : ' + sxx_y);
        // console.log('sxx_xx : ' + sxx_xx);
        // console.log('a : ' + qr['a']);
        // console.log('b : ' + qr['b']);
        // console.log('c : ' + qr['c']);

        for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
          yPoint.push((qr['a'] * x[i] * x[i]) + (qr['b'] * x[i]) + qr['c']);
        }
        qr['yPoint'] = yPoint;
        return qr;
}
```

[What my graph looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNT7h.png)

Comment: Consider upvote if this helped you so I can gain reputation. I was looking for a different question on the same subject to answer but couldn't find any.